# change value with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have button, and when I click on it it run ajax that should change "startRow" values', but it doesn't.

Why is that?
Here is the code -

```
<div id="commentsBox">
<?PHP 
    $startRow = 0;
    print_comments ($_GET['page'], $_GET['ownerID'], $startRow)
?>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="moreComments" startRow='0' pageName="userPage" refID="<?PHP echo $_GET['ownerID'] ?>">MORE</button>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function () {
    $("#moreComments").click(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var startRow = element.attr("startRow");
        var pageName = element.attr("pageName");
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
        var info = 'startRow=' + startRow + '&pageName=' + pageName + '&refID=' + refID;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/moreComments.php",
            data: info,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#commentsBox').append(data);
                startRow = startRow + 20;
                $("#moreComments startRow").val(startRow);
                //element.attr( 'startRow' , startRow);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: put an alert on failure so you know if its making the call or not...also whats info?

Comment: is that button in a form? Just showing some ajax isn't going to be enough....have you determined the event handler is even working? SHow the full code for the button and include your page load handler as well

Comment: I edited the post @charlietfl

Comment: SHowing php code that generates the button is going backwards, we don't need that. Is this form related...where's the code that triggers the ajax and defines `info`? You need to do some debugging in your browser console

Comment: I edited again - @charlietfl

Comment: ok...so the fundamentals look good. Need to know if the ajax occurs and what happens inside that request. Can see it in browser dev tools networl tab ..status, url, response body etc. Have you tried putting console.log or alert inside click handler?

Comment: We are unable to run the PHP code. If the content that is generated by the PHP code is relevant then please show us the *actual* HTML code. If it is not relevant then please remove the PHP.

Comment: Put `console.log(info);` after you declare `var info`   run the script and check you are getting what is expected in your console.

Answer (score 0):

You ajax call is ok. The problem is that you are using the jQuery selector wrong.

Instead of this:

```
$("#moreComments startRow").val(startRow);
```

You should do this

```
$("#moreComments").attr("startrow",startRow);
```

In the first one, you are trying to access to a child of moreComments and startRow is just an attribute of moreComments.

Hope it helps!